# Setting Default Keyboard Layout for Electron Application on Windows (Unable to copy UTF-8 text propely)

Tags: windows, utf-8, electron, regedit, keyboard-layout

We have this problem where a Farsi UTF-8 text that is *programmatically* copied from an **electron** application, loses encoding when pasted into one specific application and is displayed as a set of `?` characters. The issue persists even with manual text selection and copy command invoked via either context menu or `Ctrl+C`. Texts copied from other sources such as browsers or text editors are transferred just fine.

We tried `clipboard` API of electron. We also implemented our own helper to verify the issue is not with the `clipboard` itself.

We also prepended the text with **UTF-8 BOM character** before writing it to the clipboard.

One interesting observation was that once the text is pasted into some text editor and then recopied, target app received the text properly. We also noticed that changing the keyboard layout to target language when the electron app is focused, resolves the issue as well. In addition, we realized that Windows changes default keyboard layout to English when the application is launched.

Following on these clues, we configured NSIS bundler to set the default language to Persian so that maybe Windows detects it as default keyboard language as well. Description of the application shows **Persian** as the language but Windows does not respect it and reverts the language to system default upon launch.

We tried running a script on application startup to mimic a Farsi character keyboard input, creating temporary input fields, and a set of other hacks to maybe trick the Windows/application into properly handling these texts. Keep in mind we can't rely on user to perform idiotic actions on every application launch, to fix a problem that shouldn't exist in first place. That's why we need this issue to be resolved programmatically.

Right now the only solution that comes to mind is to force Windows to set the keyboard layout for our application to **Persian** via registry entries by some separate script that user need to run only once, or can be run after each installation. I'm not familiar with the windows registry entries. My searches came up empty and the results were focused on how to do it for the whole system, but we don't wanna mess with their whole system configurations since.

Any other suggestions regarding this issue is highly appreciated.

Other information that you might find relevant:

- OS is **Windows 7**.
- Target app is an accounting software and the vendor rejects to provide any support with the integration, so I have very little information about inner workings of that application.
- html `lang` attribute of electron template is set to `fa`.
- meta `charset` attribute is set to `utf-8`.
- Application is bundled with `electron-builder` and `NSIS`.